# Azure AD B2C Custom Policies - Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have created and tested custom policies in Azure AD B2C. How can I use them in my Spring Boot Java Application? Is there a way to connect these policies in my Spring Boot Application (for example using the application.yml file)?
When I execute the application and I try to sign-in, it runs the sign-in-sign-up user flow and not the steps that I've defined in my custom policy.

Thank you

Comment: Did you create a new application for your Java service? Did you include your URL in the redirect addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Each policy has a PolicyID. Review your PolicyID in the URL in which making the request and confirm it is pointing to the correct policy.

Use the [Java web application with Azure AD B2C sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/ms-identity-java-webapp/) as an end-to-end guide to set this up.

In the sample, it outlines to update the **application.properties** file which is where you define the policyID.

See [this section in configuration file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/blob/master/msal-b2c-web-sample/src/main/resources/application.properties) (policy.sign-up-sign-in is the policyID for Sign-up/Sign-up i.e. SUSI):

```
b2c.tenant=fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com
b2c.host=fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com

b2c.authority.base=https://${b2c.host}/tfp/${b2c.tenant}/
b2c.clientId=
b2c.secret=
b2c.redirectUri=https://localhost:8443/msal4jsample/secure/aad

b2c.api=https://fabrikamb2chello.azurewebsites.net/hello
b2c.api-scope=https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read

policy.sign-up-sign-in=b2c_1_susi
policy.edit-profile=b2c_1_edit_profile
policy.reset-password=b2c_1_reset

b2c.sign-up-sign-in-authority=${b2c.authority.base}${policy.sign-up-sign-in}/
b2c.edit-profile-authority=${b2c.authority.base}${policy.edit-profile}/
b2c.reset-password-authority=${b2c.authority.base}${policy.reset-password}/
```